# Hyperledger Composer events are emitted even when the current transaction fails with code MVCC_READ_CONFLICT. Is this the expected behavior?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

**The chaincode:**
        is processing a transaction and emits an event prior to exiting.

**The context:**
        create the conditions for the transaction to fail with code `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT`, which could be reproduced by a client routine submitting two asynchronous transactions, both reading and writing the same resource instance: the first will succeed and the chances are the second will be rolled back.

**The observed behavior:**
        the event is fired even when the corresponding transaction fails with code `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT`.

Comment: More details please. How are you subscribing to the events? How many peers etc?

Comment: The network is made up of 4 peers, each of them of distinct organization. One organization is designated as the single endorser. The transactions are sent by a Node based application, using a connection profile pointing to a peer and an identity of the endorser organization. Events subscription is initiated by a websockets client, through the REST server which uses the same connection profile as the Node application which sends the transactions.

Comment: I have created issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2123 to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised an issue with the fabric-node-sdk component of hyperledger fabric here about this
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-6208

From a composer point of view I think we only want to emit successful events and it's will require changes to the node sdk in order to be able to address that.